Render array elements only to certain rows / <td> of a v-table
I'm pretty new to programming / Vuejs and I came across the following problem:
I have a table with 29-31 rows (depending on the length of the month that is to be displayed). The rows have three columns / <tds>: one for a number n, the second for the weekday and the third one for a person.
I get the data for the persons via a backend request and I have put the different persons (21 entries) into an array via a computed property called "filteredPersons".
Now I want to only display a person in a td if a day is not on a weekend or a holiday (hence the function isWeekEndOrHoliday(n)). With the way my code is now, however, if filteredPersons[n] is not displayed, n increases by 1 and the person in the array with index n will never be displayed at all.
How can I fix this so that all the person's names are displayed while tds inside a weekday-row are filled with a person's name and the tds inside a weekend / holiday row remain empty?
<v-table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Weekday</th>
        <th>Person</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="n in dIM" :key="n" :class="{greyRow: isWeekendOrHoliday(n) === true}">
      <td class="tf">{{n}}</td>
        <td class="tf">{{getWeekdays(n)}}</td>
      <td>
        <span v-if="!isWeekendOrHoliday(n)">
            {{filteredPersons[n]}}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</v-table>

I tried to get access to a different iterator (not n) for my filteredPersons array but could not find a way to make it work.
Edit:
I actually managed to solve it myself! I did the following:

Use the data to create an array with the persons (filteredPersons, as used before)
Loop over the days of the month and use isWeekendOrHoliday to filter all the days that are on a weekend or holidays. Put the days that are weekdays into an array
Combine the personsArray and the weekdaysArray into an object that has the weekdays as keys and the persons as values.
Now we can use this in the template. Here is my code:

    filteredPersons(n) {
            let persons = []
            let weekdays = []
            for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
              if (this.data[`${this.year}_0${this.month+1}`] && this.data[`${this.year}_0${this.month+1}`].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                persons.push(this.data[`${this.year}_0${this.month+1}`][i])
              }
            }
            for (let i = 1; i < this.dIM+1; i++) {
                if (!this.isWeekendOrHoliday(i)) {
                  weekdays.push(i)
                }
            }
            const weekdaysAndPersons = {};
            weekdays.forEach((day, index) => {
              weekdaysAndPersons[day] = persons[index % persons.length];
            });
            return weekdaysAndPersons
          }

And then in the template
                          <td>
                            <span v-if="!isWeekendOrHoliday(n)">
                                {{filteredPersons[n]}}
                            </span>
                          </td>


This part: "With the way my code is now, however, if filteredPersons[n] is not displayed, n increases by 1 and the person in the array with index n will never be displayed at all." is hard to understand without the actual code so that we could understand the problem here.

There are a few things that you need to change in your code. First indexing and second iteration of separate array. computed property that you are using with index(n) is not helping you to display person for a day.
const getPersonForDay = (day) => {
  // Check if the day is within the range of the filteredPersons array
  if (day <= filteredPersons.value.length) {
    return filteredPersons.value[day - 1]; // Adjust index to match array indexing
  } else {
    return ''; // Return empty string if day exceeds array length
  }
},

Also in the template, you have to make the following changes: You can use n or index based on the array of objects that you prepared in the dIM array.
<tr v-for="(n, index) in dIM" :key="index" :class="{ greyRow: isWeekendOrHoliday(index + 1) }">
    <td class="tf">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td class="tf">{{ getWeekday(index + 1) }}</td>
    <td>
      <span v-if="!isWeekendOrHoliday(index + 1)">
        {{ getPersonForDay(index + 1) }}
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>

I hope my answer will be helpful to you, let me know if you have any doubts.
